# Has the USA ever sanctioned Israel?

Tags: united-states, trade, international-relations, israel, sanctions

The USA has always been a strong supporter of Israel. In comparison, USA has repeatedly sanctioned Iran. When searching if USA has ever sanctioned Israel, didn't find anything.

Has USA ever sanction Israel? or any important Israeli corporate or political organizations? If so when

Comment: Why would you expect the USA to sanction a country it "has always been a strong supporter of"?

Comment: Transfer of weapons to the middle east including Palestine was embargoed by the UN and the US/UK/France between November 1947 and May 1948. Partly due to the until then US support of self-determination for the people in the Middle East (ie European jewish colonists STAY OUT) the US administration was divided on wether to provide weapons or not.

Comment: It's pretty stupid that someone closed this question.

Comment: Could you re-phrase that, to explain which use of "sanction" you want? With no contextual clues "sanction" means to accept. I suspect you meant "sanction" as a modern abbreviation for "use sanctions against" and does anyone not think the difference matters?

Comment: what? ? ? ? how does everyone here not know what a sanction is? quit being so pedantic

Answer (score 4):

Since companies were asked about, [NSO group has recently been added](https://www.state.gov/the-united-states-adds-foreign-companies-to-entity-list-for-malicious-cyber-activities/) to the US "Entity List for Malicious Cyber Activities". This is an Israeli company who makes [Pegusus spyware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pegasus_(spyware)) for governments. Being on that list prevents US-based people or companies from exporting products or data to that company, under US Export Administration Regulations ([EAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Export_Administration_Regulations)).

The [current version of the EAR entity list](https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/documents/regulations-docs/2326-supplement-no-4-to-part-744-entity-list-4/file) contains 10 Israeli companies and 2 citizens.

Answer (score 3):

When Israel, with the assistance of Britain and France, invaded the Sinai in 1956, President Eisenhower gently reminded Israel of American largess to the country, and it would be an awful shame if that had to be stopped.

https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/president-eisenhower-and-pm-ben-gurion-on-israeli-withdrawal-from-sinai-november-1956

Comment: That is hardly a sanction, though. It's just casually mentioning the possibility of maybe reducing the amount of foreign aid you were receiving until now.

Comment: @Rekesoft - Still, one could argue its the threat of sanction. Of course the relationship between the two countries was one where the effect of a sanction could be achieved merely by taking the metaphorical foot off the financial gas pedal.